# Doing OR with multiple conditions using Optional wrapper

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I am trying to understand and use Java 8 - Optional feature. I would like to refactor this code block. Without Optional I have such a condition.

```
ClassA objA = findObject();
if(objA == null || objA.isDeleted()){
  throw Exception("Object is not found.");
}
```

I want to transform this block using Optional wrapper. I have read about filter, ifPresent functions but I could not find a way. Maybe it is simple but I am new to Java 8. I would appreciate if you could help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't use `Optional<T>` to solely replace the `if` statement as it's no better and doesn't gain you any benefit. A much better solution would be to make the `findObject()` method return `Optional<ClassA>`.

This makes the caller of this method decide what to do in the "no value" case.

Assuming you've made this change, you can then leverage the `Optional<T>` type:

```
findObject().filter(a -> !a.isDeleted())  // if not deleted then do something 
            .map(...)  // do some mapping maybe?
            ...  // do some additional logic
            .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Object is not found."));//if object not found then throw exception
```

see the [`Optional<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class to familiarise your self with the API and the methods that are available.

Comment: I was thinking to convert the object into Optional using 
 'Optional.of(ClassA)' after I get it from method 'findObject()' . I will take your suggestion into account. 'orElseThrow' is doing the opposite of first condition in filter function, I guess. Then, we should not use any more filter functions. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `Optional.of` will raise `java.lang.NullPointerException` if objA is null

Comment: I was going to write `Optional.ofNullable(ClassA)`. Sorry, my mistake. You are absolutely right about documenting for other users.

Answer (score 3):

@Eric as you mentioned in your comment, if you don't want (can't) change the return type of findObject() for some **constraints**, you can do the following :

```
ClassA objA = findObject();
Optional<ClassA> myOpt = 
             Optional.ofNullable(objA)
                     .filter(e->!e.isDeleted())
                     .orElseThrow(()->new Exception("Object is not found.");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      return list.stream()
        .filter(tmm -> tmpAddress.type() == 1)
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(()->{
                logger.error("ERROR");//something like this
                exceptionHandler.handler("some exception
                return null;
        });
```